# How to add date and time when html form is submitted in PHP pure scripting?

Tags: php, html

I am making a basic post-box management system in PHP. the postman can add 2 inputs which are 'delivered by' and 'item number'. and a button for the postman to click to submit the inputs.

Now, when the submit button is clicked, I want PHP to record the date and time of when the inputs are being submitted (so that later on I can set a mechanism to track the item duration and see how long an item has been in the box-but this is not part of the question). How do I do that?

sorry I have just started learning PHP so my current code is still very basic, and I haven't start with the Box-function.php page yet:

The HTML page:

```
<form method="post" action="Box-function.php">

Delivered by : <input type="text" name="Delivered-by"> <br>
Item No : <input type="text" name="Item-no"> <br>
<input type = "submit">

</form>
```

Note: I have seen similar questions but those questions involve using MySQL while I am not using it. it's just pure PHP and HTML.

Comment: You're not obliged to use MySQL or any other RDBMS to store persistent data. But you'll have to store it somewhere. Are you going to email it, save it to a file and in which format, store it in a Google Drive? Figure out how you intend to save the data first. However, considering you are planning to perform analytics on your data, the typical backend to use would be MySQL (or another RDBMS).

Comment: you need to store the time somewhere in order to track it (using somekind of database is mandatory for that). Btw, you can use time() function in php to get current timestamp. Which can also be converted to any date time format

Comment: What about using PHP session? is it still not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `box-function.php` page, you can get the current date and store it along with the other data.

[Getting current date](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

Do the same when the order is delivered. The difference between the two times will tell you how long the package took to be delivered.

Also, as the comments under your post say, you will have to store the data somewhere. You can't retrieve it later if it isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: I see. thank you for answering. I'm using PHP session by the way. Is it still not possible?

Comment: Sessions have a limit on how long they'll be valid for. If you want to permanently store data, you will have to use files or databases. You could just set the session duration to a large value but sessions are not meant to be used as permanent storage, nor is that a reliable way.

Comment: Noted that. thank you for the answer and explanation :)